# Call .Net from javascript in CefSharp 1 - wpf

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I'm just learning C# WPF and has been successfully implemented CefSharp, how to call .NET function from javascript, that is loaded in CefSharp?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Construct WebView via WebView webView = new WebView(url)
2. Then you can invoke RegisterJsObject method to register a js object.
3. Use javascript to invoke this js object.

The example as below:

```
public class CallbackObjectForJs{
    public void showMessage(string msg){//Read Note
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
}

WebView webView = new WebView("http://localhost:8080");
webView.RegisterJsObject("callbackObj", new CallbackObjectForJs());
```

javascript code at frontend:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    callbackObj.showMessage('message from js');
</script >
```

**Note: The first character can't be upper of showMessage method at CallbackObjectForJs**

Comment: Not implemented Exception occurred in CefSharp 33.0.0.  Anyone know of when this might be implemented.  The next version?

Comment: @CaptainBli it looks like it has been moved to `Cef.RegisterJsObject` now

Answer (score 23):

Due to `Chromium` changes starting with `63.0.0` there are major changes `Javascript Binding`. The legacy behavior still works for `Single Page Applications` and where only a single domain is used.

### New Binding Method

The new binding method has many advantages:

- Bind and unbind objects by name
- Bind a subset of objects to different pages (including popups)
- Delete/unbind a method
- Resolve a bound object dynamically

Simple example:

```
public class BoundObject {
    public void showMessage(string msg) {
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
}

browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("boundAsync", new BoundObject(), true);
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (async function() {
        await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("boundAsync", "bound");

        boundAsync.showMessage('Message from JS');
    })();
</script>
```

For more details visit [Javascript Binding v2 #2246](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2246) and [How do you expose a .NET class to JavaScript?](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript)

### Legacy Binding

*If you perform cross-site navigation's you will no longer be able to use this method to bind objects.*

You need to set `CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true` before you register your first object (`RegisterAsyncJsObject`).

Simple example:

```
public class BoundObject {
    public void showMessage(string msg) {
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
}

CefSharpSettings.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true;
browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("boundAsync", new BoundAsyncObject());
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    boundAsync.showMessage('Message from JS');
</script>
```

For more details visit [Javascript Binding v2 #2246](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2246) and [How do you expose a .NET class to JavaScript?](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript)

Comment: Awesome answer for "New Binding Method" part. Simple, crystal clear and works like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

First create a public class in C# like below :

```
public class cShaarp_Js
{
public void calledFromJs(Object object){}
}
```

And then you should register this class to your chromeBrowser.

```
chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("file:///C:/sample.html");
chromeBrowser.RegisterJsObject("csharp", new cShaarp_Js);
```

Now we are done with C#. on the other side at javascript you can create a callback to this class as done in below:

```
function cSharpMetodCall(){csharp.calledFromJs(object);}
```